# Change url based on current information

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to change url of a page in mvc 5(using c#) depending on what information it shows. Ex- let there is an action method named "getPerson" in "home" controller that displays the details of a person then the URL will be like

localhost:59772/home/getperson/

We want it to be

localhost:59772/name of the person whose details are requested.

Comment: That's what Routing is for. See for example: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Comment: You will need at least `localhost:59772/XXX/name of the person` in order to identify the controller, and then you will also need a custom route definition to set the `controller` and `action` defaults

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom routing for that.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "personDetail",                             // Route name
                "{id}",                            // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "getPerson" , id = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

OR you have to use 3rd party plugins for URL rewrite.